# Installing/activitating pgsql.so extension in CentOS 6

Tags: postgresql, php-extension, php-pgsql

I am trying to install a student information system (RosarioSIS) that is PostgreSQL-driven. After installing PostgreSQL 9.6 , the system asks me to install and activate a php extension (pgsql.so). I tried 'yum install php-pgsql' command, but it didn't work for some reason. I have tried all the suggested solutions on Stackoverflow and other forums, but still no luck. The last thing I tried is unarchiving a copy of php 5.4.45 and compiling the extension manually using:

```
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This also did not manage to add the pgsql.so to the folder extension. What do you suggest I do in order to add the required extension (pgsql.so) to where it belongs?

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.6 release date is far earlier than PostgrSQL 9.6 (PG96). When PHP56 is released, it wasn't knowing about PG96. Try installing PostgreSQL 9.3 and you'll see everything works great. BTW, even PHP7.1 doesn't have client library for PG96 in FreeBSD ports tree.